# Subversion E160013: '/svn/xxx/!svn/me' path not found* error

Tags: apache, svn

I recently upgraded the [bitnami trac stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/trac) (from 0.12.2-5 to 0.12.3) on our server and after reconfiguring all the scripts and repositories all seemed well. I was able to login and view the source code and browse through the repository using [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). I tested checking out the source code and I could browse the repository via both visualsvn and tortoise.

But when it came to commiting changes made there was a problem. I got a path not found exception. Looking into the error log on the server, all I could see was that all GET requests were fine, but POSTs had an incorrect URL (`!svn/me` was appended at the end).

After spending a couple of hours going through logs and configurations, since Subversion was upgraded from 1.6 to 1.7, this include the [new HTTPv2 protocol](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#httpv2). This protocol somehow affected access to the SVN repositories, but only seems to affect POSTs and not GETs.

## Workaround

The way to disable this new feature is by changing the [mod_dav_svn](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html) configuration as follows:

```
DAV svn
...
SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol Off
```

The issue was then resolved and we could check in our changes again.

Comment: This may not fit the normally accepted Q&A format of SO, but who cares? It saved me. I initially saw this and brushed it off as I didn't see an answer, but after trying practically everything else for hours, stumbled upon it again. Thank you!

Comment: This question is a perfect answer!

Comment: You probably should edit this post to make it a question and then edit the post below to make it an answer to your question.  That way you can mark it as solved!

Comment: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-users/201203.mbox/%3Cjkg3qq$a55$1@dough.gmane.org%3E -- here the same issue is discussed, but there is no solution :(

Answer (score 8):

I resolved this by disabling the HttpV2 protocol. To disable it you can make changes to the `mod_dav_svn` configuration locations as follows:

DAV svn
...
SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol Off

Comment: This is just a workaround, it does not fix the underlying problem. HTTPv2 should work just fine with mod_dav_svn.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add a little to this "question".  I was getting the same error message after I relocated a SVN server from one machine to another.  A 500 error and "!svn/me" was appended to the end of the SVN server URL, nothing would commit but everything else worked.  After hours trying numerous things, it turns out that the user account VisualSVN / Apache was using didn't have write access to the SVN repo's directory.  So I gave the account modify / write access ot he SVN repos directory and committing worked.  Which actually makes sense because everything but Commit was working.  Not sure if this will be helpful for others but I thought I would post it here regardless.  Thanks for the question, helped me understand where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem on https://trac-hacks.org, which serves Trac at `/` and Subversion at `/svn`. The issue was initially worked around by disabling `SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol`. Later the issue was resolved by serving Trac from `/trac` and redirecting `/` to `/trac`. However, that solution was not ideal due to the redirect. Another admin on the project found the solution of adding:

```
Alias   /svn            /var/www/000-default/svn
```

I'm not sure why this works, but it effective and doesn't require the redirect and serving Trac from `/trac`.

Answer (score -1):

My repository has about 700 000 files and 660 folders. I had the same error, and was sure that `SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol Off` is not the right way to go. Adding

```
<IfModule dav_svn_module>
    SVNInMemoryCacheSize 262144
    SVNCacheFullTexts on
    SVNCacheTextDeltas on
</IfModule>
```

to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: nor your answer neither `SVNAdvertiseV2Protocol Off` works for me.