# Creating tags in SVN from trunk

Tags: eclipse, svn

We are using SVN for data repository. I've created **branches** for our project successfully from eclipse
Now i am trying to create **Tags** so that i can put the project releases over there. But when i am trying to create "Tags" from eclipse its giving me following error.

> Get repository folder children operation failed. svn: E160013: URL
>   'svn://svnsrv.yash.com/svn/repo/MyProject/tags' non-existent in that
>   revision

Please suggest what to do to create **"Tags"** from eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion E160013: '/svn/xxx/!svn/me' path not found\* error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928285/subversion-e160013-svn-xxx-svn-me-path-not-found-error)

Comment: Can you use the command line? svn copy svn://svnsrv.yash.com/svn/repo/MyProject/trunk svn://svnsrv.yash.com/svn/repo/MyProject/tags I think should do the trick. If not, what plugin are you using to interface with SVN from Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Subversion 1.8.9 and SVNKit 1.8.3

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Kepler and svn Eclipse 1.8.8. The solution was:

SVN perspective> Select repository> New> Folder ... And put: tags

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Location properties..." of you repository (right click on the repository at "SVN Repositories" view). Then to "Advanced" tab and disable "Enable Structure Detection". This also applies to the same error when trying to create branch for some folder outside of the trunc. 
See [Error while creating branches and tags with SVN from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867684/error-while-creating-branches-and-tags-with-svn-from-eclipse)