# Error while creating branches and tags with SVN from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, branch, subversive

I am getting the whole time error messages while creating new branches or new tags with the SVN plugin (Eclipse Subversive).
The error message ist just like

```
Get repository folder children operation failed.
svn: E160013: URL 'file:///Users/****/svnrepository/branches' non-existent in that revision.
```

I tried already to create the branches folder manually and then update the local project, but it did not work. Does anybody have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. In the ***SVN Repositories*** view **right-click the repository** and choose: ***New > Project Structure...***
2. Choose e. g. *Monolithic layout* and click ***OK***
3. **Right-click the repository** again and choose: ***New > Branch...***

Answer (score 0):

1. In the SVN Repositories view right-click the repository and choose: New > Project Structure...
2. Choose [Single project or multiple projects layout] and click OK