# Getting `svn: E160013:` when merging from command line

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I have an issue with a feature branch that I'm trying to merge to `trunk`. The message that I'm getting is this:

`➜  trunk  svn merge https://svn.vcshost.org/svn/domaindev/branches/Master-Project/feature-branch
svn: E160013: '/svn/domaindev/!svn/bc/112033/trunk/Master-Project' path not found`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried merging from `trunk` to this feature branch and it worked flawlessly, also merging other branches to `trunk` works okay, so I'm guessing that there's a problem with this exact branch.

EDIT: I also tried merging using relative URLs but have encountered the same issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can find the solution 


   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928285/subversion-e160013-svn-xxx-svn-me-path-not-found-error

Comment: I went over this question in my search for a solution but this does not apply to me as my issue is only with this branch. With any other branch I can work without a problem. What I ended up doing was creating a clone branch from trunk, replace its contents with the old branch comtents (except for the .svn/ dir) and I managef to perform the merge to trunk. I kept the old branch intact (where I cand commit and pull and merge TO) for its history log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to my question was creating a fresh branch, checking it out locally,  and copying the codebase from the faulty branch, except for the `.svn` dirs. Commit, update, merge! Kept the faulty branch for its commit history.