# Jenkins maven release subversion copy failed

Tags: jenkins, maven-release-plugin

While releasing Java module from Jenkins, the system shows following logs :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mypro 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) @ mypro ---
...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/workspace/mypro && svn --username myuser --password '*****' --no-auth-cache --non-interactive copy --file /tmp/maven-scm-1889961268.commit --parents --revision 001 https://myhost/svn/repos/mypro/tags/myparent-1.0.1/mypro https://myhost/svn/repos/mypro/tags/mypro-1.0.0
...
[ERROR] svn: E160013: '/svn/rpos/!svn/rvr/001/mypro/tags/myparent-1.0.1/mypro' path not found
```

The pom.xml definition is :

```
<groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>mypro</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myparent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </parent>
```

The subversion repository structure

```
|--myparent
   |--trunk
   |--branch
   |--tags
|--mypro
   |--trunk
   |--branch
   |--tags
```

Is it possible to use maven parent feature on distinct project ?

Is there a way to configure maven-release-plugin to use "/mypro/trunk" instead of "/mypro/tags/myparent-1.0.1/mypro" as the source path in the subversion copy command ?

Thanks

Comment: Remove your <parent> tag from pom.xml and configure the path of your source code in Jenkins. Possible try [SVN: E160013 Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873678/getting-svn-e160013-when-merging-from-command-line)

Comment: The page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992213/maven-parent-pom-vs-modules-pom shows differences between parent and module pom. In my case, I need to use a parent in a separate project to be able to use it over all other projects. Is it possible to use maven in such case ?

Comment: Is there a way to switch the svn source for copy command throw release plugin parameters ?

Comment: The problem was caused by the module pom configuration. The scm section has been copied from the parent to the module pom and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure maven-release-plugin to use "/mypro/trunk" instead of "/mypro/tags/myparent-1.0.1/mypro" as the source path in the subversion copy command ?

Make sure that your respective `Module POM` was configured to the same `SCM` as is in `Parent POM`.

**References#:**

[Maven SCM configuration](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM)